# How to identify a specific decreasing trend in data in R?

Tags: r

## Question

In the presence of increasing and decreasing trends in data, how do I identify a specific decreasing trend?

## Data

I have 3 variables in the data frame `v4`. `Time` is the time in seconds, `sacc` is the acceleration (or deceleration) of a vehicle, `dV` = vehicle speed minus lead vehicle speed (in same lane) and `Vehicle.ID2` is the unique ID of the vehicle pair. Following are example data for 1 pair:

```
> dput(v4)
structure(list(sacc = c(1.3, 0.9, 0.05, -0.03, -0.5, -1.5, -0.4, 
0.2, 0.36, 0.37, -0.04, -1.5, -2.4, -1.7, -2.2, -0.003, -4e-04, 
4e-04, 0.002, 0.02, 0.3, 1.6, 1.5, 0), dV = c(4.2, 5.7, 6.6, 
7.3, 7.4, 7, 6.5, 6.6, 6.7, 7.1, 7.6, 7.5, 6.7, 4.3, 2.4, 0.16, 
0.11, 0.04, -0.009, -0.17, -0.9, -0.7, -0.6, -1.5), Time = 1:24, 
    Vehicle.ID2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), class = "factor", .Label = "1-2")), .Names = c("sacc", 
"dV", "Time", "Vehicle.ID2"), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")
```

`dV` continuously increases or continuously decreases. You can see in the attached line plot that `dV` increases for some time, then decreases, increases again until observation number 11. At this point, due to continuous deceleration (negative `sacc`) the `dV` continuously decreases until it becomes zero (both vehicles moving at same speed) and then negative (lead vehicle speed is faster than following vehicle).

[image]

## What I want to do:

I want to identify this specific decreasing trend when `dV` goes from some positive value to the first negative value. Then I want to get the total time during this. In the example data, total time between 19th (dV becomes negative) and 11th (dV starts decreasing) observations is 8 seconds.

## What I tried:

I can find the point where the `dV` becomes negative:

```
require(dplyr)
v4 <- v4 %>% 
group_by(Vehicle.ID2) %>% 
mutate(trend_dV = sign(dV)-sign(lag(dV)))
```

But after this I am clueless. Please guide me how I can find the specific decreasing trend?

Comment: I want to find that decline which makes `dV` negative. Then I will have two points. The first one where the decline started (positive `dV`) and the second where `dV` becomes negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
v4$delta <- NA
for(i in 2:nrow(v4)){
    v4$delta[i] <- v4$dV[i] - v4$dV[i-1]
}

v4$start_flag <- 0
for(i in nrow(v4):2){
  if(v4$delta[i] > 0 & v4$dV[i] > 0){
    v4$start_flag[i] <- 1
    break
  }
}

v4
```

> ```
>       sacc     dV Time Vehicle.ID2  delta start_flag
> 1   1.3000  4.200    1         1-2     NA          0
> 2   0.9000  5.700    2         1-2  1.500          0
> 3   0.0500  6.600    3         1-2  0.900          0
> 4  -0.0300  7.300    4         1-2  0.700          0
> 5  -0.5000  7.400    5         1-2  0.100          0
> 6  -1.5000  7.000    6         1-2 -0.400          0
> 7  -0.4000  6.500    7         1-2 -0.500          0
> 8   0.2000  6.600    8         1-2  0.100          0
> 9   0.3600  6.700    9         1-2  0.100          0
> 10  0.3700  7.100   10         1-2  0.400          0
> 11 -0.0400  7.600   11         1-2  0.500          1
> 12 -1.5000  7.500   12         1-2 -0.100          0
> 13 -2.4000  6.700   13         1-2 -0.800          0
> 14 -1.7000  4.300   14         1-2 -2.400          0
> 15 -2.2000  2.400   15         1-2 -1.900          0
> 16 -0.0030  0.160   16         1-2 -2.240          0
> 17 -0.0004  0.110   17         1-2 -0.050          0
> 18  0.0004  0.040   18         1-2 -0.070          0
> 19  0.0020 -0.009   19         1-2 -0.049          0
> 20  0.0200 -0.170   20         1-2 -0.161          0
> 21  0.3000 -0.900   21         1-2 -0.730          0
> 22  1.6000 -0.700   22         1-2  0.200          0
> 23  1.5000 -0.600   23         1-2  0.100          0
> 24  0.0000 -1.500   24         1-2 -0.900          0
> >
> ```